# Linking two.js with dat.GUI

Tags: javascript, dat.gui, two.js

I want to link the change `letter.linewidth = 10` with a control in dat.GUI.

Here is the code for the full `letter` variable:

```
var letter = two.interpret(document.querySelector('.assets svg'));
    letter.linewidth = 10;
    letter.cap = letter.join = 'round';
    letter.noFill().stroke = '#333';
```

To add an element to dat.GUI it says in the docs "`The property must be public, i.e. defined by this.prop = value`", though when I add `this.` in front of `letter.linewidth` it breaks the functionality of two.js and does not interpret the SVG.

I'm kinda' new to JavaScript and having a tough time figuring this one out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier! Glad you found the fix. I think you need to add it as an answer though — instead of just updating your original question. I'd love to see what you're making. It's rudementary, but post an issue on the [Two.js Issues](https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js/issues) to share anything you've made as well if you have any other questions. I get emailed directly when that happens... Happy coding!

Comment: Hey @jonobr1, I did not expect to see you commenting here! Thanks for creating Two.js! I will post updates of what I'm working on soon, as the project is now going into the production phase (doing my Masters in college). The code above was for a proof of concept presentation earlier this month. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lots of playing around, I found the fix.

Here is the code to draw the SVG through two.js:

```
var letter = two.interpret(document.querySelector('.assets svg'));
letter.linewidth = 100;
letter.cap = letter.join = 'round';
letter.noFill().stroke = '#272727';
letter.scale = 1;
```

I was calling the letter wrong with dat.GUI. Here is my code for dat.GUI:

```
window.onload = function() {
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(letter, 'linewidth', 1, 100);
}
```

I don't know if this will be useful for anyone, but hey, hopefully this will help if somebody is running into the same problem.